# How to set permanent alias

Tags: linux, bash, awk, alias, system-administration

Can anybody help me to set following script as alias:

```
ps axu | awk '{print $2, $3, $4, $11}' | head -1 && ps axu | awk '{print $2, $3, $4, $11}' | sort -k3 -nr |head -20
```

I tried adding below line `.bashrc` file

```
alias abc='ps axu | awk '{print $2, $3, $4, $11}' | head -1 && ps axu | awk '{print $2, $3, $4, $11}' | sort -k3 -nr |head -20'
```

But had no luck, I am getting below error

```
$abc
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]... sort: read failed: /apps/: Is a directory Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

Comment: In theory, you can get rid of the `awk` command by telling `ps` which columns to print. In practice, good luck figuring out how. Perhaps `ps -opid,pcpu,pmem,comm ax`?

Comment: `ps -e --sort -pmem -opid,pcpu,pmem,comm | head -20` very nearly does what you want, avoiding the need for `awk` or `sort`, although as far as I can tell it won't sort on the `pmem` field.

Comment: Thanks everyone for prompt reply!!!

Comment: The ``$11`` from the ``awk`` command is best replaced by ``args`` in the ``ps`` output specification, not with ``comm``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a tip: don't call `ps` twice: pipe the output to a group of commands. As a function, you'll have much less quoting grief.

```
abc() {
    ps axu | awk '{print $2, $3, $4, $11}' | {
        IFS= read -r header && echo "$header"  # the first line
        sort -k3 -nr | head -20                # all the rest
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this going to drop the first line from the sorted output? i.e. Shouldn't it be `{ echo "$header"; cat; } | sort -k3 -nr | head -20` or something like that? Or are you assuming the sort will drop that line out anyway so it doesn't matter (it being the header and all))?

Comment: I'd use `tee` (if it matters): `ps | awk | tee >( read -r; echo "$REPLY" ) | sort | head`.

Comment: That is what I think the OP wants (what he *should* want, I mean): show the header and sort the rest of it.

Comment: Yeah, I realized after I asked that the sort probably makes this fall out as intended (and that the goal was likely what you thought it was).

Comment: I wrote function instead of alias and it worked! Thanks
abc() {
ps axu | awk '{print $2, $3, $4, $11}' | head -1 && ps axu | awk '{print $2, $3, $4, $11}' | sort -k3 -nr |head -20
}

Answer (score 1):

The command `ps` is very configurable. This two commands are almost equivalent, your selection by awk, and a configured ps format:

```
ps axu | awk '{print $2, $3, $4, $11}'
ps axopid,pcpu,pmem,comm
```

Where the user `u` formatting was replaced by an special format `o pid,pcpu,pmem,cmd`. Is is similar, not identical only because of the command name and some formatting. We will get to that a bit later.

If the command name is not a deal breaker, ps could even sort by some selected key with the `k` option, and selecting only 20 lines we get:

```
ps axopid,pcpu,pmem,comm k-pmem | head -20
```

Which replace all the selecting, sorting, and formatting of your initial command. That should be enough for all practical uses I think.

But if you do need an identical output as your original, we need to expand the command to show all args. Such output is very long for some commands and doesn't format well. Additionally, the awk processing you used could NOT be reproduced by plain ps. We need to cut the command part in the first space and, to get a better formatting we need some printf love.

All said, this gets exactly the same output (well, a bit better formatted):

```
ps axopid,pcpu,pmem,cmd k-pmem | head -20 | awk '
    {gsub(/ .*/, "", $4); printf "%5s %4s %4s %-.50s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4}'
```

And, just making it a single line to make its use a little easier to copy/paste:

```
ps axopid,pcpu,pmem,cmd k-pmem | head -20 | awk '{gsub(/ .*/, "", $4); printf "%5s %4s %4s %-.50s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4}'
```

And so, the alias becomes only one line.

I hope you will be able to get the alias working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where `grep` is coming from but your problem is that quotes don't nest like that.

When you stuck the single quoted awk scripts inside single quotes for the alias the quotes match-up incorrectly.

Replace each "inner" single quote with `'\''` and it should work.

```
alias abc='ps axu | awk '\''{print $2, $3, $4, $11}'\'' | head -1 && ps axu | awk '\''{print $2, $3, $4, $11}'\'' | sort -k3 -nr |head -20'
```

Comment: awk: '{print
awk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
awk: '{print
awk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression

Comment: It worked for me in a quick test but glenn jackman's answer is better.